# How to convert rules stored in Database in form of vb.net code?

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

We have a requirement where we have rules stored in a database table and from those rules we need to validate certain attributes at runtime.

The Table below depicts similar structure from where we will pull the Attribute Name and their respective rules to be evaluated based on the Rule_ID.

Example: If I want to validate attribute **FirstName** I need to check that FirstName attribute should not be null and must contain some value. If this is attribute is not having any data an error needs to be thrown against this attribute.

```
RULE_ID ATTRIBUTE_NAME      ATTRIBUTE_RULE
ABC123  FirstName              <> NULL
XYZ345  LastName               <> NULL
GHI654  Age                    <>NULL
POC123  DateOfBirth            < Sysdate
QWE675  BloodGroup             = A+ve
JKL987  City                   <> London
IUK134  Occupation             = NULL
```

As the Rules stored in the database will be in Varchar i.e. String, how can we convert these rules which are in string and validate the attribute in the code using vb.net?

Kindly help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar to this although you will need to adapt as you see fit.

Basically I created a series of functions which returned a boolean result

e.g. a Function to test for not blank...

```
Protected Function CheckNotBlank(value As String) as Boolean
    If value <> "" then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

a Function to test for Is less than numericvalue...

```
Protected Function CheckIsLessThan(value As Integer, compareToValue As Integer) As Boolean
    If value < compareToValue Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Then you could have a series of checks....

```
Dim ValidFlag as Integer = 0
Dim ErrorStack as New StringBuilder

If CheckNotBlank(MyValueToCheck) = False Then
    ValidFlag += 1
    ErrorStack.Append("MyValueToCheck is Blank ").Append(vbCrLf)
End If
If CheckIsLessThan(CheckIntegerValue, CompareToIntegerValue) = False Then
    ValidFlag += 1
    ErrorStack.Append("CheckIntegerValue is greater than CompareToIntegerValue ").Append(vbCRLF)
End If
If CheckNotBlank(AnotherValueToCheck) = False Then
    ValidFlag += 1
    ErrorStack.Append("AnotherValueToCheck is Blank ").Append(vbCrLf)
End If
......
If ValidFlag > 0 Then
  'We have errors
End If
```

You would need to create and adapt your functions to suite. Hope that Helps!